# Can I "force" parallel execution of dependent targets?

Tags: shake-build-system

Say I have a target `A` that depends on `B`, but I can run `A` and `B` in parallel. Is this possible with Shake? It seems like `need ...` makes actions sequential which totally makes sense, of course, but this is a "special" case.

Comment: Why is it safe to run `A` and `B` in parallel even though `A` depends on `B`? In what sense does it depend on `B`?

Comment: (apologies for late reply) Those files go through a validation process that checks whatever is imported so if A imports B, when A is checked B will also be checked, so both "actions" can run in parallel. However, I would like to ensure that A gets "rebuilt" whenever B changes.

Comment: Great, sounds like a `need` at the end is sufficient - so the answer below should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

```
"A" %> \_ -> do need ["B"]; ...
"B" %> \_ -> ...
```

If you do `need ["A","B"]` then it will start `A` and `B` in parallel, but the `A` action will immediately pause until `B` is complete. For what reason is it safe to run `A` and `B` in parallel? If the action computed by `A` needs to rerun when `B` changes, but doesn't actually use `B` itself you can reorder to be:

```
"A" %> \_ -> do ...; need ["B"]
```

However, if the action in `A` actually uses `B` then there is no real way to run them in parallel.